# CPLEX: Using Sum in Sum for CPLEX Coding

Tags: syntax, cplex

I am quite new to this platform and I was searching for an aid for my currently running project. I currently have some problems over writing a sum function in a sum function in CPLEX.

To give a brief information about my problem, here goes a tiny part of my decision variables and my objective function:

```
dvar boolean y[Amount][Address][Floor][Lane];

minimize sum(i in Amount, j in Address, k in Floor, l in Lane) y[i][j][k][l];
```

As parameters, I do not face any trouble except the Address parameter. I have the Address parameter in a form as follows:

The general formulation is `Address[i]`, and I have `Address[1]=40` , `Address[2]=12` , `Address [3]=24` etc...

I need to implement the Adress[i] parameter to my decision variable and objective function. So I definitely need to change the Address part to Address[i] and need to have another sum in the objective function. The following one was my idea:

```
minimize sum(i in Amount, j in (sum(i in Address[i]), k in Floor, l in Lane) y[i][j][k][l];
```

But CPLEX does not accept this syntax. It says I have an "`syntax error, unexpected ','`" usage. The ',' is the one that comes after "`j in (sum(i in Address[i])`". I can clearly see that I am not able to code down my idea in the given form, and I was wondering if it is possible to have such a sum function in a sum function. I took a look at the internet links but I failed to find sufficient information about my situation.

So, is it possible to implement a sum in another sum function?

I am very sorry if this problem was asked before, but I couldn't really find something sufficient. Thank you for your kind answers and mind blowing advices. You are the bests.

Regards,

Comment: not sure if i understand your problem: you minimize the boolean dvar so you have the amount of your y, but you actually want to mimize the sum over all Adress[i]? So if one of your conditions would be have at least 2 y right now you would get 2, but you want to have the lowest 2 values of Address (12 + 24 in your example)?

Comment: Actually, no. It was just a part of my objective function, I have some further decision variables but this part was my troubled one. Let me give an example please:

Let's say I have Address[1]=40 , Address[2]=12.

my ranges are as follows:

range Amount = 1.. nAmount;
range Address[i] = 1..nAdress[i];
range Floor = 1.. nFloor;
range Lane = 1.. nLane;

I want the model to take a look at y[1][1][1][1],  y[1][2][1][1], ....,  y[1][40][1][1] for Address[1].

And y[2][1][1][1], y[2][2][1][1], ... , y[2][12][1][1] for Address[2].

Am I clear? Let me know it is not understandable

Comment: yes but i am not sure if it is possible. Can you fill up the array with 0 or `infinity`, depending on what should happen? like Address[1] has 40 values and Address[2] has 12 and then 28 0 or `infinity`. Then you would have the same size in the Array

Comment: If Address[i] is a single number, why would you need to do a sum over its single value?